# PostgreSQL Remote Connection debugging

Tags: centos, remote, port-forwarding, postgresql

I'm having issues connecting to my PostgreSQL database from an online source.

PostgreSQL seems to be setup up fine it is running on it's default port 5432 and the postgresql.conf has the following line

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And the pg_hba.conf has the following

```
host    dbname    usname    all    md5
```

I can connect to the PostgreSQL database from a different machine using the following credentials in pgadmin

```
Name              local
Host              192.xx.xx.xx
Port              5432
Maintenance DB    dbname
Username          usname
Password          psword
```

Using these I can connect perfectly it seems to work fine.

Then I forwarded the port 192.xx.xx.xx:5432 on the ADSL router and checked it using the public IP address 197.xx.xx.xx (visible to the internet IP)
http://www.canyouseeme.org/
Where I can see the port was forwarded ok.

I've disabled SELinux and disabled the firewall temporarily as well.

However when I try to connect using

```
Name              online
Host              197.xx.xx.xx
Port              5432
Maintenance DB    dbname
Username          usname
Password          psword
```

I get the server doesn't listen error message

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "197.xx.xx.xx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Why is this? Do I need to add an extra step to making it accept connections through port forwarding?

Comment: x-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/33502476/398670

Comment: what does x-posted mean?

Comment: I'm linking to the duplicate you posted elsewhere, so others don't waste time commenting on this one or answering it without first seeing the other one.

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't know that was a thing

Answer (score 0):

`all` isn't valid in the CIDR field of a `host` line in `pg_hba.conf`.

From the comments in the default `pg_hba.conf` file itself:

> # host       DATABASE  USER  CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTION]

and

> CIDR-ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.
>   It is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is an integer
>   (between 0 and 32 (IPv4) or 128 (IPv6) inclusive) that specifies
>   the number of significant bits in the mask.  Alternatively, you can write
>   an IP address and netmask in separate columns to specify the set of hosts.

Try this instead:

```
host    dbname    usname      197.xx.xx.xx/32  md5
```

that will allow connections to dbname from usname only from remote host 197.xx.xx.xx

If you want to allow the entire 197.xx.xx /24 subnet, use:

```
host    dbname    usname      197.xx.xx.0/24  md5
```

Comment: I tried changing the pg_hba.conf to "host   all   all   0.0.0.0/0   md5" but still no luck

Comment: 1. don't do that.  it'll be wide open to the internet when this problem is solved.  limit it to just the host(s) and/or network(s)  that need access.  2. do you have any firewall rules blocking access to port 5432?

Comment: I've changed the pg_hba.conf to your recommendations "host   dbname   usname   197.xx.xx.0/24" and "host   dbname   usname   192.xx.xx.0/24"

Comment: I tried to use "telnet 197.xx.xx.xx 5432" from another machine and I got "telnet: connect to address 197.89.125.31: Connection refused"

Comment: I don't think it's to do with the firewall because it is disabled at the moment for testing and so is SELinux

Comment: When I telnet from the same computer to 192.xx.xx.xx 5432 it says "Connected to 192.168.20.66 (192.168.20.66)" absolutely baffling, is there something wrong with my ISP

Comment: not that baffling.  1. postgres is on a private network behind an adsl router. 2. you can connect from inside the network.  3. you can't connect from outside the network.  4. conclusion: you haven't correctly configured your adsl router to port-forward port 5432 to your postgres server.

Comment: btw, are you trying to telnet to 192.x.x.x from your 197.x.x.x machine?  there's no way at all that can work because 192.168.0.0/16 **is not routed on the internet**.  It's private address space only.  You need to connect to your ADSL router's internet-side IP address.  if the router is configured correctly, it will forward the connection to the host on the private IP.

Comment: I thought that too but then what is necessary to port forward PostgreSQL, I added the LAN ip address of the server running postgresql and the 5432 port for TCP

Comment: I was trying to telnet to the internet-side IP address from a completely different computer on the LAN

Comment: did you try running tcpdump or wireshark (on the postgres host) to see if the packets are being forwarded?  e.g. if the network interface is eth0 `sudo tcpdump -l -n -i eth0 port 5432`.   then try to connect while the tcpdump is running.   if tcpdump isn't installed, install it first, of course.